# Timestamp Splitting incorrect - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime

I've a Timestamp loaded from MSSQL into a Webclient.
The Timestamp is: Thu Jan 01 18:00:00 CET 1970,
but i need only the: 18:00 or 18:00:00 (first one is the better one..)

```
<script>
          var timestamp = "{{SYSTIMESTAMP}}";
          var time1 = timestamp.split("T")[1].split(".")[0];

</script>
```

The HTMLcode for the function is:

```
 <span class="systime"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(time1)</script></span>
```

The output is:

**hu Jan 01 18:00:00 CE**

--> I need 18:00 or 18:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Timestamp is: Thu Jan 01 18:00:00 CET 1970

Assuming you have that as a *string*, client side:

```
var str = "Thu Jan 01 18:00:00 CET 1970";
```

The simplest way to get "18:00" from it is a simple regular expression:

```
var m = /(\d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2}/.exec(str);
var result = m && m[1];
```

You said just `"18:00"` was better, but **if** you wanted `"18:00:00"`, just move the closing `)` to the end, just before the `/` that ends the regular expression.

**Live example**:

```js
var str = "Thu Jan 01 18:00:00 CET 1970";
var m = /(\d{2}:\d{2}):\d{2}/.exec(str);
var result = m && m[1];
snippet.log("Result: '" + result + "'");
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```